# labeltext in the tableview cell disappears when tapped on the cell only in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, ios7

This is my code to populate a tableview:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        CellIdentifier = @"lcell~iphone";
    } else
    {
        CellIdentifier = @"lcell";
    }
   lcell *stockCell = (lcell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (stockCell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        NSLog(@"CEll loaded1");
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                stockCell =  (lcell *) currentObject;
                            NSLog(@"CEll loaded2");
                        break;
            }
        }
    }

     //Here setting the label text andg getting the label text of all cells correct even in ios7
     stockCell.headerlabel.text= [[self.reserveArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];
     NSLog(@"title %@",[[self.reserveArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title]);
     stockCell.headerlabel.tag=indexPath.row;
     stockCell.headerlabel.numberOfLines = 1;
     stockCell.headerlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
     stockCell.headerlabel.minimumFontSize = 0;
     stockCell.headerlabel.numberOfLines=2;
     return stockCell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
}
```

When tapped on the cell the label or the label text disappears in iOS7. It works on all other iOS versions. Any pointers to resolve this issue?

Comment: can you provide the implementation of your custom "lcell" UITableViewCell please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `UITableViewCell`:

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```